# Running Jekyll on Windows 7

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm having an issue with running Jekyll on windows 7.  When I run

```
jekyll
```

I get the following error

```
C:\temp\jekyll\kouphax.github.com> jekyll
Configuration from C:/temp/jekyll/kouphax.github.com/_config.yml
Building site: C:/temp/jekyll/kouphax.github.com -> C:/temp/jekyll/kouphax.github.com/_site
unit-testing
You are missing a library required for Textile. Please run:
  $ [sudo] gem install RedCloth

ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
------------------------------------
Missing dependency: RedCloth
```

However RedCloth IS installed

```
C:\temp\jekyll\kouphax.github.com> gem install RedCloth
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed RedCloth-4.2.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for RedCloth-4.2.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for RedCloth-4.2.8...
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the instructions [here](http://hblg.info/2011/08/27/RedCloth-fix-Windows-installation.html) and that fixed my problem.

> After gem install RedCloth run redcloth.bat from \Ruby\bin (replace \Ruby\ with the Ruby installation dir).
>
> If it complains about not finding the path 1.9/redcloth_scan then do the following:
>
> Create a dir named 1.9 in \Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\RedCloth-4.2.8\ext
>
> Copy everything from \Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\RedCloth-4.2.8\ext\redcloth_scan in the 1.9 folder just created.

Comment: Link 404.  Please put complete version in your answer (as well as the link) to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the gems and reinstalling them. RedCloth first and then Textile so that it makes sure to see RedCloth.

(I'm new to ruby, so that may not even make sense, but it seems like it's worth a shot.)

Answer (score 0):

Try download and reinstall the [latest ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) ,then follow this [instruction](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Install), good luck!

Comment: This link makes no mention of Windows.

Comment: you can install [gitbash](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) on windows, then follow the instruction, good luck!